# Creating a function that calls previously defined variables using the first part of the variable name

Tags: python, function, variables, call, defined

I'm trying to build a function that automatically calls previously defined variables using a portion of the name of these previously defined variables.

For example:

```
List=('USGS46', 'USGS47', 'USGS48', 'USGS50')

USGS46_d17O= -15.6579
USGS46_d18O= -29.4758

USGS47_d17O= -10.48288938
USGS47_d18O= -19.8374292

USGS48_d17O= -1.144217023
USGS48_d18O= -2.210739818

USGS50_d17O= 2.583133734
USGS50_d18O= 4.920460156

for x in List:
    print(print(f"{''+x+'_d17O'}"))
```

I figured that print within print would first provide the variable name and then call it but instead I just get a 'None' returned for each.

```
USGS46_d17O 
None 
USGS47_d17O 
None 
USGS48_d17O 
None 
USGS50_d17O 
None
```

How can I get this to actually provide the values associated with each?

Comment: Also, you mixed up the different ways to insert a variable into a string. Use either `x + '_d17O'` or `f'{x}_d17O'`.

Comment: Hi all, thank you for the quick responses! Yes; the following posts mostly address the issue I'm having. I just had to switch from 'print(print(f"{''+x+'_d17O'}"))' to 'print(eval(f"{''+x+'_d17O'}"))' and it worked! As mkrieger1 pointed out, I have now simplified this to 'print(eval(x+'_d17O'))'. I really appreciate the help!

Comment: Use a dict, not individual variables!

Comment: Why did you choose `eval()` and not `globals()` or `getattr()`? Their respective answers are higher-voted. And they don't have a warning below them printed in bold text.

Comment: @deceze
this is for a dict but I just wanted to give a brief example of the issue

Comment: @mkrieger1 seemed like the most straightforward/simple solution for me but I'm fairly new with Python

Comment: This is what you want: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1373185/476! Do not get into nonsensical habits with variable variables.

Comment: @deceze I hear you. Like I said, I was using dict in the actual code I just gave a brief example here to save time. Thanks again for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The print function's return value is None.
When you `print(print(...))` it will first call the inner print function, which will just print the actual string each time, and this inner print will return a `None` value, which will later be printed.

To print the value of a variable given a string, you could use the function `eval()`
so it would end up being:

```
List=('USGS46', 'USGS47', 'USGS48', 'USGS50')

USGS46_d17O= -15.6579
USGS46_d18O= -29.4758

USGS47_d17O= -10.48288938
USGS47_d18O= -19.8374292

USGS48_d17O= -1.144217023
USGS48_d18O= -2.210739818

USGS50_d17O= 2.583133734
USGS50_d18O= 4.920460156

for x in List:
    print(eval(x+"_d17O"))
```

Comment: Thank you! Some of the earlier comments helped me find this answer but still really appreciate the help!

Comment: What would be the equivalent to this solution in R? I'm once again getting stuck in the same spot using (eval((paste0(x,"_d18"))) in R?